# How to produce original xml file from differences?

Tags: xml, diff

I have two xml files(original.xml and updated.xml). I find the differences between the two files with fc command on windows (or diff on a Linux environment) and save the output in txt or xml format(differences.xml).

```
fc original.xml updated.xml > differences.xml
```

Is there a way to produce the original.xml file if I have the updated.xml and the differences.xml files? May I also produce the updated.xml file if I have the original.xml and differences.xml files?

Comment: in linux see the command `patch` (to apply the differences) and `patch -R` (to obtain the original)

Answer (score 0):

If you used `diff` to make the list of changes on a Unix, say with:

```
$ diff original.xml updated.xml > differences.xml
```

you may rebuild `original.xml` by applying `differences.xml` to `updated.xml` with the `--reverse` option:

```
$ patch updated.xml --reverse -i differences.xml -o original.xml
```

`-i` is for "input", `-o` for "output". Please mind, `patch` takes the original file as a direct operand, and the diff file with `-i`, not the other way around.

Comment: Is there an equivalent method for windows?

Comment: If you have the option to generate the diff file from the updateed file to the original, you may try [TortoiseMerge](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/TortoiseMerge.html), part of Tortoise SVN /Mercurial

Comment: In case someone is interested, with UnxTools I am able to run diff and patch commands in windows os.